# How can I restrict a user to only run specific applications?

Tags: windows-xp

I am using Windows XP Professional and would like to know if there is a way to allow a user access to **only** a specific set of applications.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you in a stand alone or Active Directory environment?

Comment: I have the same question. The account is LOCAL but the computer is attached to the domain. I want to ONLY restrict the NON-Admin accounts to this.